# Blue checkmark under player's name in scoreboard

Tags: overwatch

When playing an OW match with friends I will see a blue checkmark that shows up under a player's name from time to time. I don't know what it's for and I'm curious what exactly is it for.

[image]

I have never seen it under my own name, so it must be an indicator for something; what does the blue checkmark represent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It lets you know whether that player's ultimate ability is available. If there's a checkmark, then they can unleash their ult at any time, and if it's not there, then they're still charging.